# How can I change the color of the class field with monokai theme?

Tags: python, colors, themes

I tried in several ways to modify the color of this class through the json file in vscode but without any success.

The theme I'm using is Monokai.

Hope someone can help me.

[vscode snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2TPX.png)

Try to edit settings.json file but unfortunately without any success.

I tried to use codes like this:

```json
        {
            "name": "Function argument",
            "scope": "variable.parameter",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                "foreground": "#FD971F"
            }
        },
```